# java interfaces to connect to sharepoint

Tags: rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, java

I have to connect SharePoint resources using Java API for the tasks like uploading the new document and custom metadata to SP,Fetching the document list based on the filtering using the custom metadata and updating the existing document along with custom metadata to SP.

**Main Actions:**

1. Storing and updating document with custom metadata
2. Fetching documents based on document metadata(Using custom metadata filtering)

Please highlight some Java API to do the above tasks.

Comment: Have you find any relevant api please ?

Answer (score 1):

Check the API from github below.

[Sharepoint Java API](https://github.com/quantr-research/Sharepoint-Java-API)

[Java Sharepoint REST API](https://github.com/clintonbosch/sharepoint-rest-interface)

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look of this project i've developed where you'll find a working API that will provide you some common operations to perform against a sharepoint site. It covers all the use cases you want to achieve and some more and it is very easy to use

https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java